# Use endpoint notification (interrput based) of usb cdc acm

Tags: usb, cdc

Every USB CDC ACM has a three endpoints: 
1. notify
2. data IN.
3. data OUT.
Can we use notify endpoint for our application purpose?

Comment: Actually 4 endpoints. You forgot to add control.

Answer (score 0):

in USB protocol any communication is initiated by the host, the device can only answer to requests. even if the device has an interrupt pending it has to wait until the host sends an interrupt request to the endpoint.
you can query if the notify endpoint with an *interrupt transfer*

**http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb4.shtml#Interrupt**

in `libusb` is the function

`int    libusb_interrupt_transfer (struct libusb_device_handle *dev_handle, unsigned char endpoint, unsigned char *data, int length, int *transferred, unsigned int timeout)`

http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__syncio.html

**http://janaxelson.com/usb_virtual_com_port.htm**

Comment: Thanks . will check that